# How can I add quotes to a char?

Tags: c, quoting, mplab

I need to add quotes in begging and ending of a char.

```
char *Mychar = "hello"; 
printf("%c\n",Mychar[0]);
```

My result is `h` and my desired result is `'h'`.

Comment: A `char` is specifically a single character, you can't have multiple characters inside one `char`, that's what `char[]` is for. If you just need to **print** `'h'`, then you can do `printf("'%c'\n",Mychar[0]);`, note the single quotes inside the double quotes.

Comment: Code **cannot** add `'` to a `char`.  Code **can** add `'` to a _string_ or to a `printf()`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like`char *Mychar = "hello";
  char quote_string[4] = {'\'', *Mychar, '\'', '\0'};
  printf("%s\n",quote_string);` which prints `'h'\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them in the format string. For single quotes, you can just put them in there:

```
printf("'%c'\n",Mychar[0]);
```

For double quotes, you'll have to escape them:

```
printf("\"%c\"\n",Mychar[0]);
```

Comment: Thank sir. Is it possible to add it before printf? char *Mychar = "hello"; 
char test='\n,Mychar[1],'\n;?

Comment: @user8978978: You could use `const char *Mychar = "'hello'";` or `const char *Mychar = "\"hello\"";`.  (The `const` is semi-optional; you can't modify a string literal reliably -- it will crash your program on many systems -- so the `const` is appropriate to let the compiler know you know.)

Comment: I need to get 'h'

Comment: @user8978978 `%c` can only format a single character. `'h'` is 3 characters, it needs to be a string.

Comment: i need to separate each char of a string with single quote in front and in end.Examle string hello i need to take 'h' , 'e', 'l', 'l' ,'o' in a string